# What, if anything, can a person accomplish who has intercepted an emailed QR image for Authenticator?

Tags: multi-factor, authenticator

A web hosting company has emailed me a QR code so I can have Authenticator generate a 6-digit PIN to use as the second factor after I've logged into my portal with username and password. What, if anything, could a person accomplish who had intercepted the QR image the hosting company emailed to me? Presumably the interceptor would also know the identity of the sender organization and my email address. If they couldn't accomplish anything harmful to me with those three pieces of information, what additional piece(s) of info would they need to do anything nefarious?

Comment: Is the QR code generated once in the beginning once you created your account and they never send another different QR code again to you, or is it generated for each time you want to login?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by ‘Authenticator’? Do you mean some custom app for this service? _Google_ Authenticator? _Microsoft_ Authenticator?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know there were multiple possibilities there. Google Authenticator.

Comment: As to how often the QR code is generated,  it is not each time I log in, but they can resend it if there are problems, which they actually did do, since my PINs were being rejected. Now I have two entries for the website in Google Authenticator, one with an identifier in sitename-username format and the other in username-sitename format .

Comment: Can you say how 'What… can a person accomplish…' differs from 'What can a person/one do…'?

Either way, how might anyone 'intercept' anything e-Mailed 'for Authenticator'… unless you meant not 'intercept' but 'happen to receive'?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin  It is possible for a "bad actor" to intercept email using a number of tactics,including phishing and man-in-the-middle. As to your question about the language of the question, you have not parsed the question properly; it is not "emailed 'for Authenticator' " (i.e. not "on behalf of Authenticator") but "an emailed QR image for Authenticator"; the phrase  "for Authenticator" modifies "QR image" similar to "the key *for* the front door".

Comment: @Tim Sorry. Who here might not have realised 'bad actors' could intercept e-Mails and how might that matter?

The Question is what might be done by one intercepting an e-Mail; not how or by whom it was intercepted. Not how might e-Mail be intercepted; not even how might e-Mail for or concerning be intercept

As to your doubts about the language of the question, you have not begun to understand the parsing of the passage. You're welcome to Post your ides in any language forum but here, even the slightest chance you might be right would have no bearing on Information Security.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Sorry, I'm not following you. I asked a question, so I wasn't making any assertions that I could be right or wrong about. My question does assume that it's possible for email to be intercepted. Are you taking issue what that assumption?

Answer (score 51):

They will be able to initialize Authenticator and to produce at any time the same 6-digit PINs as you. Not less and not more.

If they don't know your password, you are still safe. But effectively the 2FA will be reduced to 1FA, not for any party, but only for those who has got this QR code.

Comment: @Nelson, no, the QR code contains the TOTP secret, which doesn't change; so it is valid indefinitely.

Answer (score 11):

> A web hosting company has emailed me a QR code so I can have Authenticator generate a 6-digit PIN to use as the second factor after I've logged into my portal with username and password.

This will depend on exactly which authenticator application you are using.

Answers for two most common ones:

**Google Authenticator and other TOTP Authenticators**

Google Authenticator uses the [TOTP standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password). The TOTP QR code contains a secret which can be reused and is enough to set up the authenticator on attacker's own system. Then they still need to obtain or guess your username and password, and they can log in as you. The phone never communicates directly to the server.

**Microsoft Authenticator with Microsoft's login service**

Microsoft Authenticator supports both TOTP and a Microsoft-proprietary [PhoneFactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneFactor) method. The PhoneFactor QR code contains an URL with what appears to be a one-time code, which cannot be reused after you have set up the application yourself. The phone can directly receive login requests from the server and pop up a message.

---

The type of data contained in the QR code can be viewed with a QR code decoder app. Be mindful that the QR code decoder might also steal your data..

**TOTP codes look like**: `otpauth://totp/<domain>/<user>?secret=<secret>&issuer=<issuer>`

**Microsoft's codes look like**: `phonefactor://activate_account?code=<code>&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmobileappcommunicator.auth.microsoft.com%2Factivate%2F<code>`

There are of course other, less common applications called "Authenticator" that may or may not permit reuse of the QR-code after one phone has been added.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the PhoneFactor one-time-use code in the QR code/URI? The wiki link is to the tech/company.

Comment: @schroeder Unfortunately no, [Microsoft's FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/common-questions-about-the-microsoft-authenticator-app-12d283d1-bcef-4875-9ae5-ac360e2945dd) doesn't mention re-use. It can be observed in practice that it gives [error message](https://students.senecacollege.ca/spaces/186/it-services/forums/microsoft-multi-factor-authentication-frequently-asked-questions/4392/when-i-scan-the-qr-code-it-tells-me-that-its-qr-code-already-used-what-can-i-do) when you try to do so.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find technical docs either. Observation works for now. Fortinet has a similar protocol, but its proprietary (or was 10 years ago).

Comment: If you are you using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-based_one-time_password then they will desync very fast.